# Snowflake - Add string value before each row value for specific columns

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this simple query that is joining 2 tables to get me the access token (Note: there is only 1 token in each row) from one table and the respective story id from another table. I am then executing this statement (setting `fetch_all = True`)

I'm thinking my next step using Python is to loop through each story id (there can be several csv's in 1 cell) and use the respective access token.

So I'm wondering if I can add `id:` before each `story_id` and `token:` before each `access_token`

Query:

```
select
story.story_id,
info.access_token
from story_table story
join page_info info
on info.account_info_id = story.account_id
where to_date(story._load_datetime) = '2021-12-23'
```

The results look like this:

| story_id | access_token |
| --- | --- |
| 23434234, 4353221342, 123424 | dkf832sfd |
| 82348234234 | dkfjds832sdf |

Comment: if you are going to loop through each `story_id`, would it make more sense to flatten the data out and have the SQL produce a row for each `story_id`?

Comment: @MikeWalton I think I understand, you mean separate out each comma separated story_id into its own row? but then will it have the correct access token?

Comment: If I understand you correct , are you trying to build dictionary in python like below with above data set for each record.  thisdict = {   "id": [23434234, 4353221342, 123424],
"access_token": dkf832sfd
}

Comment: @Anand yes a dictionary would work and I would want the dictionary value to be for each story_id, so for example the first cell I showed in my example would have 3 different dictionary key values

Comment: So can you place some screen shot to see what is your exact o/p would be and  so i can  build and place code which helps you to add additional changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH x AS (
  select
  story.story_id,
  info.access_token
  from story_table story
  join page_info info
  on info.account_info_id = story.account_id
  where to_date(story._load_datetime) = '2021-12-23'
  )
SELECT y.seq, y.value::string as story_id, x.access_token
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN (input => SPLIT(story_id,',')) y;
```

The result of this is a line per story_id with the correct access_token.  If you wanted to append text to the output and the re-aggregate that back again, let me know and I will update this answer.

Comment: these id's you hardcoded there are many more values in my table. Is there another way I can do that without doing ('23434234, 4353221342, 123424','dkf832sfd'), etc

Comment: Again, I was just imitating the data you showed in your example.  If you replaced the query with your SQL, it will still work...let me update the query.

Comment: Updated using your original query.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much! can I ask, what is the purpose of y.seq?

Comment: You don't need it.  I was just showing you that these were coming from the same original record.  If for some reason your python logic needed to know that, you could leverage it.  Otherwise, just remove it.